# How to use strpos to determine if a string exists in input string?

Tags: php, strpos

```
$filename = 'my_upgrade(1).zip';
$match = 'my_upgrade';

if(!strpos($filename, $match))
    {
    die();
    }
else 
   {
   //proceed
   }
```

In the code above, I'm trying to die out of the script when the filename does not contain the text string "my_upgrade". However, in the example given, it should not die since "**my_upgrade(1).zip**" contains the string "**my_upgrade**".

What am I missing?

Comment: strpos returns the numeric position of the match.  Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`strpos` returns `false` if the string is not found, and `0` if it is found at the beginning. Use the [identity operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to distinguish the two:

```
if (strpos($filename, $match) === false) {
```

By the way, this fact is documented with a red background and an exclamation mark in the [official documentation](http://php.net/strpos#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues).

Answer (score 11):

**The `strpos()` function is case-sensitive.**

```
if(strpos($filename, $match) !== false)
        {
        // $match is present in $filename
        }
    else 
       {
       // $match is not present in $filename 
       }
```

**For using  case-insensitive.** 
use `stripos()` that is it finds the position of the first occurrence of a string inside another string (case-insensitive)

Answer (score 5):

```
if (strpos($filename, $match) === false)
```

Otherwise, `strpos` will return `0` (the index of the match), which is `false`.

The `===` operator will also compare type of the variables (boolean != integer)

Answer (score 2):

```
false === strpos($filename, $match)
```

The [`strpos` function<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/strpos) returns `false` if not found or `0` if found on position `0` (programmers like to start counting at `0` often):

> **Warning** This function may return Boolean `FALSE`, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to `FALSE`, such as `0` or `""`. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the `===` operator for testing the return value of this function.

Answer (score 1):

`strpos` returns `false` if the string is not found, and `0` if it is found at the beginning.

so try this:

```php
if (strpos($filename, $match) === false) { 
       conditon
}
```

Note we use a strict comparison (`===`) If we don't, both types (`false` and `false` or an integer) will be coerced to the same type, and `0` when coerced to a bool is `false`.

more details: https://zdevtips.com/guid/strpos-in-php-example4-example-codes/

Comment: Why are you answering a question with the same answer as others already provided like 9 years ago?

Answer (score 0):

This working for me when everything other fail in some situations:

```
$filename = 'my_upgrade(1).zip';
$match = 'my_upgrade';
$checker == false;
if(strpos($filename, $match))
    {
    $checker == true;
    }
if ($checker === false)
{ 
die();
}
else 
{
//proceed
}
```

Or in short:

```
$filename = 'my_upgrade(1).zip';
$match = 'my_upgrade';
$checker == false;
if(strpos($filename, $match))
    {
    $checker == true;
//proceed
 }
if ($checker === false)
{ 
die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$data = 'match';
$line = 'match word in this line';
if(strpos($line,$data) !== false){
    echo "data found";
}else{
    echo "no data found";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

strpos in this case will return a zero, which is then interpretted as false when you do the logical negation. You should check explicitly for the boolean `false`.